# Doing laundry as a tourist in Russia

Tags: russia, clothing, laundry

I'm planning a several week trip to Russia (Moscow and Yekaterinburg specifically) , and I want to pack as lightly as possible --- ideally, I want to be able to do laundry, so I don't have to bring enough clothes for every day of the trip.

On that note: are there laundromats in Russia where tourists can go to do laundry? Or do hotels normally offer a laundry service? If not, are there alternatives? Or do I need to resort to washing clothes by hand in the hotel bathroom?

Comment: There are self-service laundromats in Russia, though maybe not as commonly found as elsewhere in the world. Search for прачечная-автомат.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks! do you know if they tend to take rubles or do you have to buy special tokens?

Comment: It depends... You might have to use coins, or a really modern place might have you load credit onto a card, which you then use at the machines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Laundromats are *very* rare; I can hardly remember seeing any in my life (actually, I can't remember exactly whether I have seen them, I can just think of some places where they may have been). I guess that if you ask a random person, they will not help you.

There are places where you can drop off your clothes and the next day receive it clean (ask for химчистка khimchistka or прачечная prachechnaya), but the interval differs (some may offer an option for quick cleaning — several hours, — some may require a week), and some may refuse some types of clothing.

At the same time, I think that most hotels and hostels do offer laundry services. However, as always, better check when booking.

Comment: This site shows some I believe... http://www.samprachka.ru/adresa-prachechnyix-v-moskve.html

Comment: Have you actually looked for Laundromats? It is amazingly easy to miss seeing them when you do not need them, even when they are there.

Comment: @Willeke, yes, I've never actually looked for them.

Comment: If you were to look for them what would be the best phrase to put into Google Maps? ПРАЧЕЧНАЯ САМООБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ or something different?

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes, "ПРАЧЕЧНАЯ САМООБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ", but also like "Автопрачечная" "автостирка" etc, because the format is not widespread, thus different names may be used. Also I would be using 2gis (2gis.ru) instead of google maps, as it is has much more complete data.

Comment: Forget laundromats, they are as hard to find as unicorns. And also there is serf who "automates" part of laundromat work for you, LOL. However, there are regular laundry shop and they are much more common.

Answer (score 7):

Russian apartment almost universally has a washing machine.

This means when you rent an apartment (via AirBnB or even Booking or by googling "квартиры посуточно {city}", the apartment will usually have an operable washing machine and some detergent. If you ask for it in advance you can arrange apartment with washing machine confidently.

So your best bet is sometimes renting an apartment (as opposed to hotels and hostels), making sure that apartment has washing machine, and using it to wash your clothes (note that drying machines are unheard of so you will need to hang clothes on overhead wires or balcony or furniture doors:)

Comment: I suppose dryers are unheard of mostly in the figurative sense.  Surely commercial laundries have them and people are aware that they exist.

Comment: @phoog people here are mostly oblivious to their existence. I don't think I ever saw one in Russia. Commercial laudries are not common as you could guess from the rest of answers.

Comment: If commercial laundries are uncommon, who washes the sheets and towels in the hotels?

Comment: @phoog Common Russians do not stay in hotels that often, and when they do they don't give much contemplation about how they wash their sheets (russian saying about "knowing how sausage is made" goes here). So unless you work for a hotel or commercial laundry, good chances you have never heard about drying machine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I've never been to Russia, but I've spent a lot of time in different parts of former Yugoslavia where everyone similarly has a washing machine at home and dries their laundry by hanging.  Such an arrangement was also common in the Netherlands when I lived there some years ago.  I suspect that people there know what driers are but don't have room for them and/or don't want to pay for the energy to operate them.  But I could be wrong; next time, I'll ask.  And of course the situation in Russia could well be different.

Comment: Can confirm that separate hot air dryers are pretty much unheard of in Russia, though some newer and fancier washing machines do have that function. While some tech stores [do sell](https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/large_and_small_appliances/large_appliances/electric_dryers/) driers as separate units, most people's apartments are cramped enough already to have room for another giant box that just sits there and collects dust most of the time, so most people don't bother to even remotely consider buying one.

Answer (score 5):

Just google "химчистка золушка" - this is a very common laundry service in Russia.
For example in Sankt-Petersburg - http://zolushkaspb.ru/adress/ ( sorry - only in Russian language, and staff will speaking only in Russian, so be ready for that).

Comment: You are not affiliated with them, are you?

Comment: No of course, just in not "capitals cityes" like Moscow or St Petersburg, Volgograd for example - where I live now, this is single common laundry service. In Volgograd that laundry service exists even in shopping moll (Ашан).

Comment: `химчистка` ("dry cleaning") is often aimed at cleaning single but complex items (such as dresses or furs). If this is the case they may be puzzled when you give them your 10 pairs of socks, and the price may be surprising since it will be per-item. Maybe they also do laundry by kg, but that's not for granted.